# In laravel 5 What's the appropriate Entity and the correct location to interface my app with a (custom) external service?

Tags: php, web-services, laravel-5, interaction

I have developed already an App (http REST service) in laravel 5.
I takes POST input params, elaborates them and return Json as elaboration result.

Now I'm developing a second App in  Laravel 5, this second app must use the first one's services.

Basically I would create one or some interface classes that create the input to be sent, open the remote connection with the other service, send input and parse the answer.

What's the correct Laravel way to have it done?